# Empty Dataframe after being populated from URL

Tags: pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

```
html_data = requests.get('https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/GME/gamestop/revenue')

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data.text, 'lxml')
all_tables = soup.find_all('table', attrs={'class': 'historical_data_table table'})

gme_revenue = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Date", "Revenue"])

for table in all_tables:
if table.find('th').getText().startswith("Gamestop Quarterly Revenue"):
    for row in table.find_all("tr"):
        col = row.find_all("td")  
        if len(col) == 2: 
            date = col[0].text
            revenue = col[1].text.replace('$', '').replace(',', '')
            gme_revenue = gme_revenue.append({"Date": date, "Revenue": revenue}, ignore_index=True)
```

however, when I try to make a table, it comes up empty as

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Date, Revenue]
Index: []
```

and after I do a test, this appears:

```
gme_revenue.empty
>>>True
```

unsure on why my data frame is empty. I've even copied the code from another data frame and it still doesn't work.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
if table.find('th').getText().startswith("Gamestop Quarterly Revenue"):
```

to

```
if 'Quarterly' in table.find('th').text:
```

and it should work

Output:

```
Date    Revenue
0   2020-10-31  1005
1   2020-07-31  942
2   2020-04-30  1021
3   2020-01-31  2194
4   2019-10-31  1439
... ... ...
59  2006-01-31  1667
60  2005-10-31  534
61  2005-07-31  416
62  2005-04-30  475
63  2005-01-31  709
64 rows × 2 columns
```